# Is Multiple Connection available with 6LoWPAN over BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, observers, coap

I am in trouble with implementing multiple 6LoWPAN connections over BLE networks.

I am implementing multiple CoAP observers and a Crossproxy using Raspberry pi 3 B model (BLE 4.1).
When one device (CoAP Server) is connected to a gateway (CoAP Client) by 6lowpan, communication between them is ok.

```
IoT Device (RPI): BLE Slave role -----
Gateway(RPI): BLE master role (Communication ok)
```

But, one more devices are connected to a gateway by 6lowpan, the communication is blocked.
When I checked packets using WireShark, a gateway keeps sending request packets but other devices do not receive any packets (no receiving packets in wireshark).

```
IoT device(RPI): BLE slave ---------------+
Gateway(RPI): BLE master (Nok)

IoT device(RPI): BLE slave ---------------+
```

I am wondering that 6LoWPAN over BLE does not support 1:N communication.
When I searched the web, I only found 1:1 6LoWPAN topology not N:1 topology.

Is there a solution to connect multiple devices to a master in 6LoWPAN over BLE?

Comment: Could you please clarify - do you mean multicast sending or just a server with N clients?